# Xamarin Forms iOS crashes with FileNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app which runs perfectly fine under Android on both the emulator or my physical device. However, when I try and run the iOS project, it fails on startup when its setting up the `SQLLite` connection/configuration.
Its throwing a `FileNotFoundException` complaining about `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

This is referenced in the portable class project (and set Copy Local to true) and the model class that has the Data annotations works fine on Android. Indeed, if i look in

```
<my app path>\<myapp>.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug
```

I can see System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll in there. But for some reason the app is crashing:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs:GetCustomAttributesDataInternal (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider)
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesData (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.11.0.126/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:303 
  at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.MemberInfo target) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.11.0.126/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/CustomAttributeData.cs:119 
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetCustomAttributesData () [0
x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.11.0.126/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:463 
  at System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.11.0.126/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/memberinfo.cs:51 
  at SQLite.TableMapping..ctor (System.Type type, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00100] in <9b4aaa86123841b8bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.GetMapping (System.Type type, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00028] in <9b4aaa86123841b8bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00028] in <9b4aaa86123841b8bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<CreateTablesAsync>b__0 () [0x0002b] in <9b4aaa86123841b8bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Version
```

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or have any idea how I can diagnose it?

Thanks

Comment: Try to also reference it from the platform project

Comment: I have it referenced in the platform project, but thats the Mono port as the full framework assembly isnt available. I've tried adding it directly (from the filesystem) and that made no difference either.